# How to convert SOAP-based WCF service to RESTfull API

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

Now I am having SOAP based WCF service, How can i convert that to RESTfull API.

My WCF Service will look like this.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICategoryService
{
    [OperationContract]      
    bool UpdateCategory(CategoryEntity category);     
}


[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class CategoryService: ICategoryService
{
}
```

Comment: you can look up how to use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class in C# is an option

Comment: Depends - do you want it to be RESTful WCF, or a non-WCF RESTful service?  If the latter, take a look at WebAPI.

Comment: Hi MethodMan & Tim , Thanks for your reponse. I want it to be RESTful WCF