# What is the best way to Converting SOAP-based WCF Service to RESTful Design

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, wcf, soap

I am having SOAP services in my existing project code.
Which consume XML and produces XML as my response.

I need convert of enable this SOAP to RESTful webservice by producing "Application/JSON".

- So please suggest is there any tool to convert SOAP to REST or any other way of re-using SOAP as Restful service.
- What is the best way of doing or exposing it.

I trying to analyzed what is the best way to do and refer different [links](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590627/Converting-SOAP-based-WCF-Service-to-RESTful-Desig),[links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736596/how-to-convert-soap-based-wcf-service-to-restfull-api)

But I could find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service) but this is little more generic but i am looking for some concrete and specific to .Net (C# or VB.Net) Implementation.

It will be great help for me and for any one in the future if any one would like to share the best way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two main approaches: (1) use WebGet, WebInvoke attributes so that your existing WCF service can expose both SOAP and REST endpoints.  This is covered in the first link you provided.  The downside is that your existing service might not have semantics that map easily on to a "RESTful" API.  (2) Create a new REST service that is essentially a façade to your existing SOAP service.  In this case you have more flexibility in what you expose in your REST API, and more flexibility in your choice of technologies (e.g. you can use Web API or Web API 2 rather than WCF).

Comment: To be frank I am new  to .NET may be my question is little wider. Those all terms you use is very new or not much familiar for me . 

I was working in java system try to implement this with my little knowledge . 

So if you could suggest or show some basic example of Web API which is having similar implementation for REST/ SOAP. IT will be great help. 

I can do explore on the term that you mention like WEB API rather than than WCF in mean time.

Comment: you need some basic knowledge of the technologies you are considering, so probably your question is too broad for StackOverflow.  ASP.NET Web API is a technology for building REST applications - this could be a good option for building a facade to an existing SOAP service (which may be written using WCF or some other technology including java - you haven't made this clear).  This is option 2 above.  On the other hand, if you have the source code of an existing SOAP service written using WCF, adding WCF attributes to enable a REST endpoint may be appropriate (option 1 above).